# 320 x 240 netbeans emulator

Tags: netbeans, java-me, emulation, midp

Does anyone know where I can get a java me emulator with 320 x 240 screen size for [netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org), and how I can install it?

Answer (score 1):

You can download any latest version of netbeans IDE from internet. 320 x 240 is generally the default value for the emulator. Although you can edit the size of emulator in the

> project's properties->abilities->ScreenHeight/ScreenWidth.